# Jupyter Notebook not executing cells/code

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

For some reason today my Jupyter Notebook has decided it doesn't want to execute the code in cells. However this isn't consistent. I'll restart the kernal, it will work for a while, but then when it runs into an error it then won't execute any code in any other cells after that without a kernal restart.

I've seen a previous post on this but using  `jupyter troubleshoot` only printed out all the packages and no useful information and I also don't appear to have nbextensions dubplicated anyway.

I'm using python 3.7.8 and Jupyter_client 6.1.6

Sorry I don't have much more information, but I'm not really sure what other information to give/look for.

Comment: You can see what's happening in the Jupyter shell itself (not the UI)- it usually will shows you what happens under the hood

Comment: I've got Anaconda Prompt open and that tells me when the autosaves happen, but gives me no info when it decides to stop executing the cells.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of errors do you mean by "when it runs into an error it then won't execute any code in any other cells after that without a kernal restart"?

I know that if you have In [*] instead of the run number of the cell for a long time probably you have an infinite loop in this cell or an open input (an input that waiting to your answer). Is this the situation?

Comment: so for example, there will be a mistake in the code which causes an error, like trying to multiply two matrices with mismatched dimensions. It will throw the error, I'll then try to run another cell and it won't execute and instead does the following:

I run a cell, for a split second it contains [*] but then returns to blank. If the cell was executed it would normally then have a number placed in it such as [1] for example.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Jupyter which is somehow connected to Qt, see this issue on Github

https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/6526

It is probably rare...